# sign_in user if devise not working for rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

Following [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29)

I came up with this code:

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
config.include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
```

and in the controller spec:

```
before(:each) do
 sign_in user
 get :index
end

it "should have a current_user" do
 expect(subject.current_user).to_not eq(nil)
end
```

but `subject.current_user` is coming up as nil. I want to have some idea why this is so.

Comment: You are not creating the `subject` instance variable anywhere!

Comment: @jamesc how do i do that here? the wiki didnt include that